# Creating Holiday Boolean Column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with the structure below:

| date | country |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-01-01 | Spain |
| 2019-10-23 | Brazil |

And I want to add a boolean column (1 or 0) "is_holiday" to it. This column should be an indicator to wether the date (index) is a national holiday in the specific country of the "country" column or not.

I've tried a lot of differents approachs, but I can't manage to work it out.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "I've tried a lot of differents approachs" -> which ones? Please provide the code

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [holidays](https://pypi.org/project/holidays/) library.

```py
import pandas as pd
import holidays

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'date': ['2017-01-01', '2019-10-23'],
        'country': ['Spain', 'Brazil']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Function to check if date is a holiday in a specific country
def is_holiday(row):
    country_holidays = holidays.CountryHoliday(row['country'])
    return int(row['date'] in country_holidays)

# Applying the function to create 'is_holiday' column
df['is_holiday'] = df.apply(is_holiday, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks, Cainã!

I just created a dictionary to store all holidays for each country before defining the function to improve efficiency:

dict_country_holidays = {country: holidays.CountryHoliday(country) for country in df['country'].unique()}

def is_holiday(row):
...